# HTML/CSS: Display image at % screen width *up to* original width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have a simple html code that displays an image at 100% of the browser's resolution width, but have it not extend to greater than the image's original resolution width.

For instance, I have an image w/ resolution 800x600. I'd like the image to display with a width of 100% on a mobile web browser, but at a width of 800 on a computer's browser that has a resolution of greater than 800x600.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Question: Do you always know the dimensions of the image? or is that a dynamic number?

Comment: sure. some JS to run when the page loads. capture the screen size, then set a `max-width: size_captured_in_javascript px`, basically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution #1**

If you're able to link images in your CSS, you're able to use the `background-size:contain;` property `contain` will resize the image **smaller** but not larger.  It will not go above its native resolution.

CSS

```
div {
    background-image:url("linkhere.com");
    background-size:contain;
}
```

**Solution #2**
If you do not have the luxury of using CSS like this, then you could write some javascript:
Fist make sure your image is set to 100%

```
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

then the script

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = $(this).attr("src");
image.onload = function() {
    $(this).css({'max-width':this.width+'px');
};
```

**Solution #3**
If you know the dimensions of the image, you could set it as an in-line style - this may take some time if you have a lot of images
Fist make sure your image is set to 100%

```
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Then in the html, write something like this.

```
<img src="imagesource.com" style="max-width:800px"/>
```

I would write this in-line because you may have many images in which you'll have to catalog.

Comment: Okay, I've researched it a bit, and yeah... #2 is the only way to do it to meet the requirements of the question. Touche. But #1 and #3 still - no.

Comment: @EdT. Very respectful of you. Thank you.  1 and 3 are technically solutions, though, to your point, they aren't great solutions.  I figure I'd give a few options depending on the OPs skill set and technical abilities.  I know I work at a company where I might HAVE to do #1 or #3 because the system is so jacked up!

Comment: Fair enough. I just can't imagine how screwed up it must be to make you do that... Actually thinking about #3 solution, it's pretty much the same as #2 solution and it could work well with server side language. But using #1 solution I would cry, you would have to specify width and height properties as it would be 0 by 0 otherwise, and even if you set width to 100%, setting height would be painful, also you would need background-repeat: no-repeat;.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with CSS very easily.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: To expand on this, you can now achieve this in one line using either [min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min) or clamp().

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can achieve what you want:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .img {
    max-width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class='img' src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25000000/Facing-the-wind-the-amazing-world-of-gumball-25060558-588-339.png' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you this:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

if you're using bootstrap you can just pass that class to the selector. i.e.

`<img class="img-responsive>`

wrap it into a div and add a max-width to 800px to that wrapper